# Numpy loop performance optimization Python

Tags: python, numpy, performance, vectorization

I struggled with this function to reduce a list .
Now it turns out to be shitty slow. Well I needed 3 loops ….

Its ok with this short c-list, but is useless with a bigger list.
How can I improve this ?  colormath library is a bit faster, but I would prefer Skimage. I guess this will need some numpy magic ?

My head is already exploding.

```
import numpy as np
import copy
from skimage import color 

c_list =  [(226575, (0, 0, 0)), (18279, (10, 132, 85)), (15744, (4, 152, 111)), (8768, (85, 146, 40)), (7516, (0, 166, 129)), (7482, (136, 161, 12)),
           (7092, (31, 127, 68)), (6612, (10, 47, 2)), (6304, (61, 135, 47)), (5524, (42, 97, 7)), (5202, (157, 167, 2)), (5153, (10, 32, 9)), (4807, (49, 132, 61)),
             (3921, (48, 115, 3)), (3859, (19, 75, 1)), (3784, (115, 162, 38)), (3169, (103, 151, 30)), (2616, (60, 79, 43)), (2453, (113, 168, 92)), (2397, (45, 71, 0))]


def col_dist(color1, color2):
    rgb_color1 = [x / 255 for x in color1]
    rgb_color2 = [x / 255 for x in color2]
    color1_lab = color.rgb2lab(rgb_color1)
    color2_lab = color.rgb2lab(rgb_color2)
    return color.deltaE_ciede2000(color2_lab, color1_lab)       


def reduction_c2(color_in_list, max_colors, delta_start):      
    # input c list, max number of colors, delta E starting value
    # returns reduced list with added pixelcounts
    color_in = [list(elem) for elem in color_in_list]
    fresh_list = color_in
    while (len(color_in) > max_colors):
        i = 0
        j = 0
        color_in = copy.deepcopy(fresh_list)

        while j < len(color_in):
            c = color_in[j][1][0], color_in[j][1][1], color_in[j][1][2]

            while i+1 < len(color_in):
                c_compare = color_in[i+1][1][0], color_in[i+1][1][1], color_in[i+1][1][2]
                delta_new = col_dist(c, c_compare)
                if delta_new <= delta_start:
                    color_in[j][0] = color_in[j][0] + color_in[i+1][0]
                    del color_in[i+1]
                else:
                    i += 1
            j += 1
            i = j 
        delta_start +=1   
    color_in.sort(reverse = True) 
    return(color_in)


out2 = reduction_c2(c_list, 6, 2)
print("out new = ", out2 )
```

Comment: `del color_in[i+1]` : Python lists are not linked-lists but resizeable dynamic arrays containing object references. Thus, deleting items in the middle of the list is done in `O(n)` time. The same thing is true for Numpy (it is actually worst since append/pop at the end are not possible in-place since Numpy arrays are not meant to be resizeable). You should mark items to be deleted and them delete them all at once after the loop so to avoid a *quadratic execution time*.

Comment: CPython performs no optimization on expressions (actually almost no optimization overall). Thus, when you write `color_in[i+1][1]` 3 times, then it is recomputed 3 times. Since the code is interpreted, this can be actually take a non-negligible time, though `col_dist` is likely the bottleneck (if the `del` part is not).

Comment: Thank you for input, I will try. I actually think this will only perform well with vectorization. But it is so tricky with all the deleting.

Comment: I assume `col_dist` function is a bottleneck. Dunno how many colors you have, but you may want to precompute all possible color distances, alternatively use `@functools.lru_cache` decorator on the `col_dist` function

Comment: This is a good idea. As the deltaE_ciede2000 on its own is quite complex and slow. Doing this once should speed up. Will check if opencv has delta e and could be faster too.

Comment: @functools.lru_cache is cool,  speed boost x5. Thats nice, still a problem with a big list 1000 entries. but cool. great idea dankal444

Comment: Not sure how fast it would be (if it would work, to start with) but maybe you can provide array of all possible colors comparisons to [deltaE_ciede2000](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.deltaE_ciede2000) function. I might not understand it well, but function allows 2D input and returns array.

Comment: You are right, this could be a good starting point for vectorization, as all values are calculated at once. the tricky thing is the deleting and adding up the first value (pixelcount) before deleting it. Hard to do with numpy arrays . 3 loops is tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this algorithm is going to end up computing the distance from every color to every other color, I would suggest creating an NxN matrix of every distance, and using this matrix instead of calling `col_dist()`. This is sufficient to get a 5x speedup on your example.

Also, I would suggest using vectorization when creating this matrix. This gave me a 400x speedup.

```
def col_dist_all(colors):
    colors = np.array([color for count, color in colors]) / 255
    colors_lab = color.rgb2lab(colors)
    color_distances = color.deltaE_ciede2000(colors_lab[np.newaxis, :, :], colors_lab[:, np.newaxis, :])
    return color_distances
```

Note that when removing elements from your list of colors, you will have the issue that the index of a color within the matrix changes. Instead of deleting elements of `color_in_list`, I would suggest setting them to None and skipping over them in future loops.

If you are starting with a very large number of colors, you may want to try KMeans clustering with a euclidean metric in RGB color space, to reduce to a manageable number of colors. I found that `0.5 * np.linalg.norm(c1 - c2)` was always within a factor of 0.3 to 1 of the true CIEDE 2000 distance, and euclidean distance would be much faster to calculate.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you very much Nick. Never used NaN values in arrays. Clever idea. Only ever deleted them annoyed….
Lets see if I can handle the 3 loops and np.brainfog() does not clog my brain.

Comment: finally combined it with all the loops, and some more vectorization. Gives me a 200 - 300 speedup which is pretty cool. numpy is cool.